# How do I get access to the property of children inside of a DataGrid by the x:Name in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, children

I want to control the children's elements of a DataGrid in WPF
for example a ComboBox,
like an ordinary element like this: ComboBox1.Text = "test";

What have I tried :

XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="mygrid">
     <DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid">
    
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="The Name :" Width="120" Binding="{Binding NAMES, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CMB" Width="150">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1"
                                    
                                      SelectedValuePath="CODE"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="NAMES"
                                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                                      SelectedIndex="0"
                                      IsEditable="False"
                                      SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged"
                                      BorderBrush="#FFADEEB4" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1">
    
                                    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
    
            </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
//Finder
#region Kids
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)   where T : DependencyObject
{
    // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
    if (parent == null) return null;
    T foundChild = null;
    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);
            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            // If the child's name is set for search
            if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                // if the child's name is of the request name
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // child element found.
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundChild;
}
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)  where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
        {
            return (childItem)child;
        }
        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
#endregion



private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            var Test0 = this.FindName("ComboBox1");
            var Test1 = mygrid.Children.OfType<ComboBox>().FirstOrDefault();
            var Test2 = GetChildOfType<ComboBox>(mygrid);
            var Test3 = FindChild<ComboBox>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "ComboBox1");

        }
```

refrence : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

All of the tests are Null!

Whats is the problem ?

Comment: You should work with the bound data rather than ui. Then you would know your bound property nane and not care what your control's name is.

Comment: can you show me an example for this issue ?  note: I need specific property for some special element

Comment: Bind whatever you want to work with to a property in your row viewmodel. If that's selecteditem, bind selecteditem. If it's variable collections in the combo then bind itemssource.

Comment: @Mojtabah: How do you set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid`? And what exactly do you want to do with the `ComboBox`? Change the selected value?

Comment: that question you answered ♥ : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73527534/how-do-i-display-a-different-list-than-the-source-item-when-opening-the-combo-bo     I thought I need this way but you guide me